# Term for taking a subset of a time series by selecting one every $n$ values (to get a lower resolution)

Tags: time-series, terminology

What is the technical term for creating a new times series via sub-sequence of the indices?

Or by another method like taking the averages over some window?

The point would be to get a lower resolution time series, like going from hourly to weekly.

Answer (score 4):

There are several terms.

**Decimation** or, generically, **downsampling,** is a term for retaining values at regular intervals as used in signal processing literature.  There is a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downsampling_(signal_processing)).

**Resampling,** including **undersampling,** is a procedure of removing (or even duplicating) observations to improve the forecasting of rare events.  See [Moniz, Branco, and Torgo](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s41060-017-0044-3) for a discussion and a [Wikipedia article on oversampling and undersampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oversampling_and_undersampling_in_data_analysis#Undersampling_techniques_for_classification_problems) for brief mentions of some general undersampling techniques.

**Thinning** is the procedure of randomly removing points from a point process, where the chance of removal typically depends on the time.  See [Khoo, Ong, and Biswas](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281078551_Modeling_Time_Series_of_Counts_with_a_New_Class_of_INAR1_model) for a good description of the connection between point processes and time series as well as of thinning and related procedures.

(Warning: "Binomial thinning" of an integer time series actually is a model, often termed *INAR,* relating successive values in time.  It's a different procedure.)

**Windowed averages** appear in so many ways and so many contexts that they have many names: they are basic ingredients of *smoothers;* they result from mathematical *convolution;* they have been termed *windowed means,* *rolling means,* and (in the spatial statistical literature) *focal statistics* and *block statistics.* The fundamental distinctions among them are (1) whether the windows are overlapping or form a disjoint partition of time; (2) what statistic is retained in each window (mean, median, or something else); and (3) whether and to what extent the values may be weighted.  There are so many possibilities for this I can't give you a list of references, but instead encourage searching using these terms as keywords.

Answer (score 1):

I think *downsampling* may be what you are after. Google returns many results for [time series downsampling](https://www.google.com/search?q=time%20series%20downsampling&rlz=1C1GGRV_enDK759DK759&oq=time%20&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i65l3j69i57j69i60.732j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8); here's one relevant link to get you started: http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/query/downsampling.html